# How to invalidate cache to show updated data on a custom widget in Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity

I am setting up a custom widget in Sitefinity 13 that retrieves data from an external source and caches that data on the server-side. I need the widget data to refresh the data on whatever page it is on once that cache timeout is over, but it appears that the Sitefinity page caching mechanism will cache the rendered results of a page and won't make the call to my custom widget's controller to see if we need to update the data. I've looked into the built-in Sitefinity cache dependency functionality, like IHasCacheDependency and SubscribeCacheDependency, but that appears to be geared toward watching when a page, widget, or other item is updated through Sitefinity's mechanisms (e.g. update version of page is published). I don't see a way using that functionality to accomplish my goal.

Am I missing something with the built-in cache dependency module? What options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Instead of getting the data from your controller, you can get it via javascript call. That call can be either towards the external source or, if that's not feasible, towards a proxy api controller on your site, which in turn requests the external api. This way the page will be cached, but the JS script will run and will not be dependent on the page cache at all.
2. Create a new page cache profile in the settings, that has no sliding expiration and lasts exactly the time you need, e.g. 5 minutes. Then set that profile as cache profile of your page. This way page cache will be invalidated exactly when you need it (time-wise).